# Search for empty property fields in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: 2010, search, search-results

Is it possible to search (e.g. via the property picker in the advanced search dialog) for all items that have a specific property field which is empty?

For example:
All items with an emtpy title field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The advanced search dialog does not support this. You will need to implement a custom search Web part that leverage the [NULL Predicate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms499682.aspx) in an SQL search query.